# ¿Cuáles son la reglas que determinan que un caracter alfabético es mayor, igual o menor que otro en Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Por ejemplo si hago

```
alert("Salvaje" > "parasito");
```

o

```
alert( Global < "Rubi");
```

haciendo esto puedo obtener mayor, menor o igual (false, true etc),
pero ¿cómo lo determina JS? ¿Porque una letra es mayúscula, minúscula, por ocupar un orden dado, etc.?

Comment: javascript no es lo mismo que java, no uses ambas etiquetas de manera indiscriminada

Answer (score 1):

La comparación entre dos cadenas del caso que expones en tu pregunta viene definida en la NOTA 2 del apartado [7.2.13 Abstract Relational Comparison de la especificación ECMA Script](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/index.html#sec-abstract-relational-comparison).

> La **comparación de cadenas** utiliza un **ordenamiento lexicográfico
>   simple** en secuencias de valores de unidades de código. No se intenta
>   utilizar las definiciones más complejas y orientadas semánticamente de
>   la igualdad de caracteres o cadenas y el orden de clasificación
>   definido en la especificación Unicode. Por lo tanto, los valores de
>   cadena que son canónicamente iguales según el estándar de Unicode
>   podrían probarse como desiguales. En efecto, este algoritmo asume que
>   ambas cadenas ya están en forma normalizada. Además, tenga en cuenta
>   que para cadenas que contienen caracteres suplementarios, el
>   ordenamiento lexicográfico en secuencias de valores de unidades de
>   código UTF-16 difiere del de secuencias en valores de puntos de
>   código.

O sea, que cuando Javascript compara dos cadenas utiliza el [*orden lexicográfico*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orden_lexicogr%C3%A1fico) simple, es el mismo orden que se utiliza para ordenar las palabras en los diccionarios por ejemplo, o en las guías telefónicas.

```js
console.log("a" > "aa"); 
console.log( "ab" > "A");
console.log( "á" > "ab");
console.log( "a" > "a");

console.log("localCompare");
console.log("a".localeCompare("aa"));
console.log("ab".localeCompare("A"));
console.log("á".localeCompare("ab"));
console.log("a".localeCompare("a"));

console.log("casos complicados");
console.log( "a" > "A"); //a es mayor que A
console.log( "A" > "a"); //A es menor que a

console.log("a".localeCompare("A")); //a no es mayor que A
console.log("A".localeCompare("a")); //A es mayor que a
```

En versiones modernas de Javascript, puedes encontrar el método [`localeCompare()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare), que es parte de `String.prototype` y que trabaja también con el orden lexicográfico entre dos palabras.

Este método devuelve tres tipos de valores:

- `-1`  cuando la cadena de la izquierda tendría orden lexicográfico menor a la segunda
- `1` cuando la cadena de la izquierda tendría orden lexicográfico mayor a la segunda
- `0` si las cadenas son equivalentes

Comment: Muchas gracias Sr Cedano! Le agradezco mucho por su valiósa ayuda